# Ubuntu 18.04 slow wired connection speed

Tags: networking, drivers, broadcom

Have tried several fixes from the internet on this, no luck so far.

Just installed 18.04 on an old laptop, dual boot with Win 10.  I've played with Linux a bit before (on a Raspberry Pi) but am not tremendously experienced with it.

Machine has a Broadcom BCM5906M controller, PCID 14e4:1713 (rev 02)

When booted to Win10, the machine connects to my internal network and handles file transfers (to a Raspberry Pi OpenElec Kodi box) just fine, with "normal" transfer speeds (greater than 10MB/sec...)

When booted to Ubuntu 18.04, transfer speeds slow to a crawl, usually a bit below 100k/sec.

I've tried following directions to update the NIC driver (using latest firmware package firmware-b43-installer) with no change.

I've also tried (just for the heck of it, although I didn't think they'd do anything for internal network connections) disabling IPV6 and unchecking the "make available to others".

I ran a command that I can't remember right now that gave me a list of devices, it reported this device has a "size:" of 100Mbit/s and "capacity:" 100Mbit/s so it seems that Ubuntu is detecting the device correctly.

I've tried connecting from this machine into several other machines on the network, all with the same results.

I've tried using different ethernet cables and different ports on the switch - including testing a specific port with another machine, getting 10Mbit/sec transfer rates, then plugging this machine into the same port with the same cable and getting 100k.

Seems to me pretty definitive that:

1. The hardware in the machine is working properly - I can boot it to Win10 and with no other changes and the transfer speed works fine.
2. The network connectivity is fine - I can use the same cable and port on the switch with a different machine, which works fine...

Therefore I'm thinking it's *got* to be something in the configuration of Ubuntu...

The machine is very old - I bought it in 2009 - so I don't know if that has something to do with it but just noting here.  The fact that it's becoming dog-slow with Windows is why I'm switching it to Linux - that and to give me something to play with

What can I test that would tell me more about the problem?

I ran the commands you recommended, here's the output of them all - does this give us any clues?  I'm not seeing anything but then I don't really know this all that well..

As for something eating the bandwidth, the slow transfer rates I'm quoting are on the internal network only, and I'm the only person who uses that so it's hard to imagine.  Plus I can reboot the same machine into windows at any time and get 10MB/s transfer rates to and from the same devices on the same network...

```
sudo apt install net-tools

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
net-tools is already the newest version (1.60+git20161116.90da8a0-1ubuntu1).
net-tools set to manually installed.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

ifconfig -a

enp5s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.103  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::21f:16ff:fe01:1913  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:1f:16:01:19:13  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 14843  bytes 12837145 (12.8 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 10  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 11385  bytes 9129397 (9.1 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 17  

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 507  bytes 41848 (41.8 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 507  bytes 41848 (41.8 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlp6s0: flags=4098<BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 00:1f:3c:6c:a2:22  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

arp -a

EpsonWF3620Wired (192.168.1.110) at ac:18:26:56:ea:06 [ether] on enp5s0
HomeOffice (192.168.1.100) at 00:24:1d:d0:6e:49 [ether] on enp5s0
TMHOME (192.168.1.1) at 10:0d:7f:7d:ad:6b [ether] on enp5s0

lscpi

00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Mobile PM965/GM965/GL960 Memory Controller Hub (rev 03)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Mobile GM965/GL960 Integrated Graphics Controller (primary) (rev 03)
00:02.1 Display controller: Intel Corporation Mobile GM965/GL960 Integrated Graphics Controller (secondary) (rev 03)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB UHCI Controller #4 (rev 03)
00:1a.1 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB UHCI Controller #5 (rev 03)
00:1a.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #2 (rev 03)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) HD Audio Controller (rev 03)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) PCI Express Port 1 (rev 03)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) PCI Express Port 2 (rev 03)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) PCI Express Port 3 (rev 03)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB UHCI Controller #1 (rev 03)
00:1d.1 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB UHCI Controller #2 (rev 03)
00:1d.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB UHCI Controller #3 (rev 03)
00:1d.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #1 (rev 03)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge (rev f3)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 82801HM (ICH8M) LPC Interface Controller (rev 03)
00:1f.1 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 82801HM/HEM (ICH8M/ICH8M-E) IDE Controller (rev 03)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 82801HM/HEM (ICH8M/ICH8M-E) SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 03)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) SMBus Controller (rev 03)
05:00.0 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Limited NetLink BCM5906M Fast Ethernet PCI Express (rev 02)
06:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation PRO/Wireless 3945ABG [Golan] Network Connection (rev 02)
0a:09.0 FireWire (IEEE 1394): Ricoh Co Ltd R5C832 IEEE 1394 Controller
0a:09.1 SD Host controller: Ricoh Co Ltd R5C822 SD/SDIO/MMC/MS/MSPro Host Adapter (rev 19)
0a:09.2 System peripheral: Ricoh Co Ltd R5C592 Memory Stick Bus Host Adapter (rev 0a)
0a:09.3 System peripheral: Ricoh Co Ltd xD-Picture Card Controller (rev 05)
```

Turned off everything in the network except the router, did the ifconfig on that, no overruns.  Turned everything back on one by one, at the end of that STILL no overruns...`ifconfig -a` on that below.

Meanwhile, even with no overruns showing, problem still exists.  If I turn off everything in the network except the Linux machine and a desktop (on windows 10) that I have a drive shared out to the network) transfer speed is still 100K or less.

I also tried turning off everything (including the desktop) but turning on a Raspberry Pi that I have configured with OpenElec Kodi to be a media center (that's actually my usual target for file transfers from the Linux laptop), same result - no overruns but also slow transfer speeds.

Seems somewhat conclusive that the slow transfer speeds are unlikely to be happening as a result of unseen network traffic, to me...

```
enp5s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.103  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::21f:16ff:fe01:1913  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:1f:16:01:19:13  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 6544  bytes 1460859 (1.4 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 1  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 8308  bytes 9553991 (9.5 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 17  

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 617  bytes 50596 (50.5 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 617  bytes 50596 (50.5 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlp6s0: flags=4098<BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 00:1f:3c:6c:a2:22  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

12/14/2018 12:28 PM

Thanks, here's the output from lscpi.

For some reason, the device ("enp5s0") shows interrupt 17 in the ifconfig listing but interrupt 27 in lscpi...?

Regardless, there don't appear to be conflicts in either 17 or 27...

### Device            DMA   IRQ  I/O Ports

0000:00:02.0                   0000-0000
0000:00:1a.0                   0000-0000
0000:00:1a.1                   0000-0000
0000:00:1d.0                   0000-0000
0000:00:1d.1                   0000-0000
0000:00:1d.2                   0000-0000
0000:00:1f.0                   0000-0000   0000-0000
0000:00:1f.1                   0000-0000   0000-0000   0000-0000   0000-0000   0000-0000
0000:00:1f.2                   0000-0000   0000-0000   0000-0000   0000-0000   0000-0000
0000:00:1f.3                   0000-0000
acpi                      9 
ACPI                               0000-0000       0000-0000       0000-0000       0000-0000       0000-0000
ahci                             0000-0000     0000-0000     0000-0000     0000-0000     0000-0000
ahci[0000:00:1f.2]         24 
ata_piix              14 15      0000-0000     0000-0000     0000-0000     0000-0000     0000-0000
cascade             4
dma                            0000-0000
dma1                           0000-0000
dma2                           0000-0000
EC                               0000-0000     0000-0000
enp5s0                   27 
fpu                            0000-0000
i801_smbus               19      0000-0000
i8042                  1 12 
i915                     16 
iTCO_wdt.0.auto                    0000-0000       0000-0000
iwl3945                  25 
keyboard                       0000-0000   0000-0000
PCI                          0000-0000 0000-0000 0000-0000   0000-0000   0000-0000   0000-0000
pic1                           0000-0000
pic2                           0000-0000
pnp                            0000-0000     0000-0000     0000-0000   0000-0000
PNP0C04:00                       0000-0000
PNP0C09:00                     0000-0000   0000-0000
r852                     18 
rtc0                      8    0000-0000
snd_hda_intel:card0         26 
timer                     0 
timer0                         0000-0000
timer1                         0000-0000
uhci_hcd                         0000-0000     0000-0000     0000-0000     0000-0000     0000-0000
uhci_hcd:usb4            21 
uhci_hcd:usb5            23 
vesafb                         0000-0000

Comment: Can you post the output of the following commands: `sudo apt install net-tools` `ifconfig -a`, `arp -a`, and if the device is a PCI/PCI-e card, `lspci`. The first installs the more traditional utilities for managing network interfaces, the second is the linux equivalent of `ipconfig /a`, the third lists active connections with other devices on your network (which would say whether another device is eating up your bandwidth), and the last one will list more detail about your PCI devices, and might shed some light on what Ubuntu identifies it as.

Comment: Added details requested to the posting - is that how this is done on this forum?  It doesn't seem appropriate to add those details as an "answer" or a "comment"....  Sorry if I'm mis-using the process.

Comment: As a general rule, the more information the better. Comments are used to request information/ask what has been tried, etc whereas answers are meant to propose a possible solution to the problem. Answers can be commented on as well.

Comment: Your `ifconfig -a` output lists your ethernet interface as experiencing overruns. I've never experienced these before, but googling it indicates that your interface is receiving frames faster than it can process. This could be because of the host operating system, but far more likely is a device on your network is the cause (at least from what I see after googling the error).

Comment: Hmmm.... so if I look at the router's traffic page on the internal network it shows almost nothing - generally less than 100Kbps traffic.  And why would the same issue not be affecting transfer speed when the same machine is booted into Windows?  I'll try turning off anything connected to the network and see what happens...

Comment: Posted updated test results, starting with line 12/14/2018 9:29 AM.  Any more ideas?  Thanks!

Comment: Something else I just noticed is that your linux distro is identifying the device as "fast ethernet", which should be capable of 100Mb/s : Ethernet controller: `Broadcom Limited NetLink BCM5906M Fast Ethernet PCI Express (rev 02) 06:00.0`, I might be misreading your post, but didn't you say that Windows was only getting 10Mbits, or did you mean MBytes?

Comment: Probably MBytes.  I'd have to reboot it into Win to check and I'm not with the machine right now (it auto boots to Linux, haven't figured out how to change the remotely...) but I can tell you that normally I can transfer a 1GB file across the network in Windows in perhaps 10 minutes, where in Linux it reports many hours for the same file...

Comment: At this point I'm pretty much making a shot in the dark, but it could also be your device interrupt: which is to say, what priority your device has to use the processor. If it's sharing a priority with another device (your `ifconfig -a` shows an interrupt of 17), they could be fighting over the processor, which hypothetically could cause the overruns. To check your device IRQ, you'll need to run `sudo apt install procinfo` followed by `lsdev`. This will display the interrupts of all your devices, so you can check if any are conflicting. Specifically, you're looking at the IRQ category.

Comment: Hmmm... now it shows interrupt 27 for the device, but no conflicts.  Dead end?

Comment: I'm spent on ideas but quite curious what the source of the problem is. If I think of anything else I'll post again.